# User input with "SublimeRepl" for a python script

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I am running a simple python script and using Sublime Text 3 as IDE using SublimeRepl for user input.

The below script always prints the else part even though I give a number less than 5.

```python
num = input ("Enter the number bw 1-5")

if num in range(1,5):
    print("Valid option")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked. Input is always a String, so we need to typecast to Int.

```
num = int(input ("Enter the number bw 1-5"))
if num in range(1,5):print("Valid option")
else:print("Invalid")
```